# IOS : MPVideoView, Whats its controller & Delegate

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

This is probably because I am having a brain freeze but I don't believe I have come across MPVideoView before.

So I have a UIWebview with a HTML5 demo in it, this then plays a video (in the web view) which seems to create a new view of type MPVideoView.  IS this a private class for Apple to use to show HTML5 Video content?

Does it have any delegate methods? So I could auto play it?

Can I move the controls about,  I am guessing they are a subview of that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MPMoviePlayerController for playing HTML5 video(considering you have the link to the video)
Use the following code

```
moviePlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
initWithContentURL:videoURL];

moviePlayer1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 110);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer1.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                        selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:moviePlayer1];
[moviePlayer1 play];
```

Delegate methods can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Sorry I dont need to launch a video via HTML5, this is a presentation. that I want to question